# SSL connection to server ip address

Tags: ssl, ip-address

I have a server which equipment at remote locations on private networks connect to via the internet using SSL. An SSL Certificate for the domain name of the server is installed. I have a number of devices that go through Proxy Server to connect to the server and can't use the domain name to connect and use the server's IP address instead. Some devices connect and communicate successful. I've got a new one that gets a certificate error when it attempts connection and doesn't communicate. A WireShark log for the problem device is as follows,

```
No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     75 124.992557  cc.e.135.194          aaa.bb.165.30         HTTP     93     CONNECT xxx.yy.177.237:443 HTTP/1.1 

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     76 124.992762  aaa.bb.165.30         cc.e.135.194          TCP      60     http-alt > screencast [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=40 Win=5840 Len=0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     77 125.019946  aaa.bb.165.30         cc.e.135.194          HTTP     93     HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established 

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     78 125.021486  cc.e.135.194          aaa.bb.165.30         TCP      60     screencast > http-alt [ACK] Seq=40 Ack=40 Win=3600 Len=0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     79 125.023154  cc.e.135.194          aaa.bb.165.30         TLSv1    112    Client Hello

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     80 125.063292  aaa.bb.165.30         cc.e.135.194          TCP      60     http-alt > screencast [ACK] Seq=40 Ack=98 Win=5840 Len=0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     81 125.802441  aaa.bb.165.30         cc.e.135.194          TLSv1    590    Server Hello

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     82 125.802545  aaa.bb.165.30         cc.e.135.194          TCP      590    [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     83 125.803882  cc.e.135.194          aaa.bb.165.30         TCP      60     screencast > http-alt [ACK] Seq=98 Ack=576 Win=3600 Len=0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     84 125.806427  cc.e.135.194          aaa.bb.165.30         TCP      60     screencast > http-alt [ACK] Seq=98 Ack=1112 Win=3600 Len=0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     85 125.835481  aaa.bb.165.30         cc.e.135.194          TCP      590    [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     86 125.835606  aaa.bb.165.30         cc.e.135.194          TCP      590    [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     87 125.835607  aaa.bb.165.30         cc.e.135.194          TLSv1    98     Certificate

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     88 125.837384  cc.e.135.194          aaa.bb.165.30         TCP      60     screencast > http-alt [ACK] Seq=98 Ack=1648 Win=3600 Len=0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     89 125.839309  cc.e.135.194          aaa.bb.165.30         TCP      60     screencast > http-alt [ACK] Seq=98 Ack=2184 Win=3600 Len=0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     90 125.996227  cc.e.135.210          cc.e.135.223          UDP      93     Source port: di-traceware  Destination port: di-traceware

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     91 126.041261  aaa.bb.165.30         cc.e.135.194          TCP      98     [TCP Retransmission] http-alt > screencast [PSH, ACK] Seq=2184 Ack=98 Win=5840 Len=44[Reassembly error, protocol TCP: New fragment overlaps old data (retransmission?)]

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     92 126.126265  cc.e.135.194          aaa.bb.165.30         TCP      60     screencast > http-alt [ACK] Seq=98 Ack=2228 Win=3600 Len=0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     93 126.127579  cc.e.135.194          aaa.bb.165.30         TLSv1    61     Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Bad Certificate)

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     94 126.127769  aaa.bb.165.30         cc.e.135.194          TCP      60     http-alt > screencast [ACK] Seq=2228 Ack=105 Win=5840 Len=0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     95 126.128131  cc.e.135.194          aaa.bb.165.30         TCP      60     screencast > http-alt [FIN, ACK] Seq=105 Ack=2228 Win=3600 Len=0

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     96 126.128973  cc.e.135.194          aaa.bb.165.30         TCP      60     [TCP Dup ACK 95#1] screencast > http-alt [ACK] Seq=106 Ack=2228 Win=3600 Len=0
```

A WireShark log for a good device connection is as follows,

```
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     41 18.643335000   192.168.1.77          192.168.1.66          HTTP     93     CONNECT xxx.yy.177.237:443 HTTP/1.1 

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     42 18.686919000   xxx.yy.177.237        192.168.1.66          TCP      66     https > 57090 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     43 18.690931000   192.168.1.77          192.168.1.66          TCP      60     iee-qfx > 808 [ACK] Seq=40 Ack=62 Win=3600 Len=0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     44 18.692715000   192.168.1.77          192.168.1.66          HTTP     112    Continuation or non-HTTP traffic

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     45 18.730597000   xxx.yy.177.237        192.168.1.66          TCP      1514   [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     46 18.731017000   xxx.yy.177.237        192.168.1.66          TCP      1514   [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     47 18.853088000   192.168.1.77          192.168.1.66          TCP      60     iee-qfx > 808 [ACK] Seq=98 Ack=598 Win=3600 Len=0
No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     48 18.855235000   192.168.1.77          192.168.1.66          TCP      60     iee-qfx > 808 [ACK] Seq=98 Ack=1134 Win=3600 Len=0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     49 18.857397000   192.168.1.77          192.168.1.66          TCP      60     iee-qfx > 808 [ACK] Seq=98 Ack=1670 Win=3600 Len=0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     50 18.858940000   192.168.1.77          192.168.1.66          TCP      60     iee-qfx > 808 [ACK] Seq=98 Ack=2206 Win=3600 Len=0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     51 18.860676000   192.168.1.77          192.168.1.66          TCP      60     iee-qfx > 808 [ACK] Seq=98 Ack=2742 Win=3600 Len=0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     52 18.861709000   192.168.1.77          192.168.1.66          TCP      60     iee-qfx > 808 [ACK] Seq=98 Ack=2982 Win=3600 Len=0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     53 18.885573000   xxx.yy.177.237        192.168.1.66          TLSv1    456    Server Hello, Certificate, Server Hello Done

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     54 19.831490000   192.168.1.77          192.168.1.66          HTTP     380    Continuation or non-HTTP traffic

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     55 19.832368000   192.168.1.77          192.168.1.66          TCP      60     [TCP Dup ACK 54#1] iee-qfx > 808 [ACK] Seq=424 Ack=3384 Win=3600 Len=0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     56 19.833752000   192.168.1.77          192.168.1.66          TCP      60     [TCP Dup ACK 54#2] iee-qfx > 808 [ACK] Seq=424 Ack=3384 Win=3600 Len=0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     57 19.883478000   xxx.yy.177.237        192.168.1.66          TLSv1    113    Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     59 19.910346000   192.168.1.77          192.168.1.66          HTTP     251    Continuation or non-HTTP traffic

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     60 20.115266000   192.168.1.77          192.168.1.66          TCP      107    [TCP segment of a reassembled PDU]

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     61 20.136330000   xxx.yy.177.237        192.168.1.66          TCP      54     https > 57090 [ACK] Seq=3382 Ack=582 Win=65024 Len=0

No.     Time           Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
     62 20.171317000   xxx.yy.177.237        192.168.1.66          TLSv1    299    Application Data
```

Can anyone provide insight as to what's happening here and why some devices communicate and others don't and what best practices should be here (should I get a certificate for the IP address too?). Intuitively, it makes sense to me my certificate is for a domain name and not an IP address and so there should be problems but I have a number of devices that have been communicated this way for years without issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wireshark dump you provide is not helpful, because it only shows the information at the transport layer (TCP) and not the TLS layer. It also does not show any kind of error messages from the clients nor does it show how the clients use these proxies and how they validate the certificate.

In generally a TLS connection needs to validate the servers certificate, which includes verifying the trust chain and the name in the certificate. If the name does not match the expected name the validation must fail, because otherwise you could use any certificate to pose as some other host and thus do a man-in-the-middle attack.

This also means if access is only done by IP address then the certificate must incorporate the IP address as type IP in the subject alternative names section (and better as type DNS too because of some broken TLS stacks).

If some clients fail while other succeed than it might be that some clients use the proper hostname for verification while other don't or that some clients ignore validation errors. It is not possible to know which of these is the case based on your information.

> I have a number of devices that go through Proxy Server to connect to the server and can't use the domain name to connect and use the server's IP address instead.

A proper client creates a tunnel with the help of a http proxy (CONNECT request) and then establishes the TLS connection inside this tunnel and verifies the certificate against the original hostname. That's how proxy connections work inside the browsers. And this is what your wireshark dump shows. Usually the client does not provide the IP address of the target inside the CONNECT request but the hostname, so this might be a client which either resolved the hostname up-front or which was given the IP address and not the hostname inside the configuration. In the latter case the client will not be able to verify the certificate properly, because it does not know the hostname expected in the certificate but will expect an IP address which is not there.

Comment: Steffen, thanks for taking the time to respond. I've read your comments carefully and think I now have a clue to what's going on. Our device performs communication with a ConnectOne iChip, so I'm not sure of the details of their ssl implementation. Several months ago we changed the IP address of our servers. As mentioned, the device is behind a customers proxy server on a private network. I'll bet that their internal DNS still is pointing to the old IP address for our servers and not the new one. The iChip can't verify the certificate because its going to the wrong place.

Comment: I'm wonder what tools to use to help figure out this issue. I tried using the Openssl s_client command. I'm wondering if I ran this from the customer's private network if it might not give more detail about what's happening.

Comment: If the problem is that the customer is accessing the wrong IP than you should see traffic to this IP from the customer (with wireshark or similar). Apart from that you might use wireshark at the customer location and look into the traffic: the server response contains the certificate received so you can see if this is the certificate you expected or not. Then you know if the validation by the client is the problem or if the client connected to the wrong server.